# mysqldumpslow write output to file

Tags: mysql, file, mysqldumpslow

Is there a way to write the mysqldumpslow command output to a file?

I tried `/usr/bin/mysqldumpslow log_file /var/log/mysql/log-slow-queries.log > /var/log/mysqldumpslow.log` but I get an error saying mysqldumpslow can't find the log_file.

Excuse my lack of Linux command line knowlegde!

Comment: You don't need the "log_file" part of the command. Just use `/usr/bin/mysqldumpslow /var/log/mysql/log-slow-queries.log > /var/log/mysqldumpslow.log`

Comment: Ouch that was a simple solution.. Thanks!